# How does my system know root name server?

Tags: linux, dns

How does my system know about root name server "." when it is resolving "www.example.com."? I am using an ISP, do they have the root DNS configuration?
Bit, confused on DNS concepts.

Answer (score 3):

The root name servers are found by making a standard DNS NS query of the '.' domain.

Any DNS server that will query the public name servers will have a local copy of the root servers that it will periodically update.

One of the steps to installing a new DNS server is initially seeding these root DNS servers. Typically named root.hints. This file can be downloaded from ftp://ftp.rs.internic.net/domain/db.cache

Alternatively, you can run

```
dig +bufsize=1200 +norec NS . @a.root-servers.net
```

Which will produce

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> +bufsize=1200 +norec NS . @a.root-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29307
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 13, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 25

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.                              IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
.                       518400  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
h.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       198.97.190.53
h.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:500:1::53
j.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       192.58.128.30
j.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:503:c27::2:30
g.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       192.112.36.4
e.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       192.203.230.10
c.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       192.33.4.12
c.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:500:2::c
k.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       193.0.14.129
k.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:7fd::1
a.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       198.41.0.4
a.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:503:ba3e::2:30
f.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       192.5.5.241
f.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:500:2f::f
m.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       202.12.27.33
m.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:dc3::35
b.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       192.228.79.201
b.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:500:84::b
l.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       199.7.83.42
l.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:500:3::42
i.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       192.36.148.17
i.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:7fe::53
d.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      A       199.7.91.13
d.root-servers.net.     3600000 IN      AAAA    2001:500:2d::d

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 198.41.0.4#53(198.41.0.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 03 06:37:09 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 755
```

As you can see with that file you can resolve any host on the public internet.

Comment: Can you explain the role of +bufsize in your dig example?

Answer (score 0):

IP, Gateway & DNS Servers IPs will be provided by the DHCP Service. So, it is the DHCP Server of your ISP who is providing the IP of a locally configured DNS Server to your System.

Comment: A DHCP Server has no knowledge of the root DNS servers, it simply points the clients to the configured name server, it is the name server that will have root records.

Answer (score 0):

You contact the DNS server you specify, they then contact the list of root servers to look up who authority is on the domain example.com, that dns server then contacts this authority (the dns server on record) to resolve the ip of the host.